# How could a stone age tribe of merfolk tame blue whales?

Tags: technology, fauna, transportation, prehistoric-times

An underwater stone age tribe of merfolk captured 2 baby whales and killed the adult beast for meat.  My sea people would like to tame the young whales and use them as transport when the babies reach adulthood.  How do I train My two young whales to obey their masters?

About My Merfolk :

They are fast and strong enough to chase and kill any sea creature attacking in groups,They have an humanoid torso and a long eel-like tail and can swim in deep and shallow waters alike.

About the transportation method :

i want to use the whales as an underwater carriage made of sturdy plant matter,wood and shells.

about the tribe :

Population: 3500

Location: Coral reefs

Status: Thriving

Technology Status :They can use nets,Spears,Ropes,And hooks made of bone,Shells,Stone and plant matter for nets.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad. We need to know more about your merfolk tribe than you provide. What are your merfolk's abilities (Can they go everywhere a blue whale can, or only near the surface? Can they swim faster than a blue whale? etc.)? How big is the tribe? What challenges does the tribe face? What precise technologies do they have (the stone age lasted for a very, very long time)? What do they want the blue whales to do? Without answers to those questions, we can't answer you.

Comment: Have you researched how Orcas are tamed and trained?  What about that process doesn't work for you?

Comment: Since they have such a large population, are you planning on having them being personal pets (like horses) or like horses that pull "carriages" (metaphor to whatever is in your world)

Comment: @Seraph Myrmidon - perhaps a more unusual story would be how blue whales tame mere people and make them slaves/employees/subordinates/pets/assistants.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Now that's a great story. Gonna go see if there is any book about that... ;)

Answer (score 5):

Well, first of all, I'm assuming these "baby whales" are similar to baby whales in real life. A baby *blue* whale is 3 tons and 25 feet long, so this really depends on what species you're talking about. I'm assuming here that it is a baby blue whale.

Baby blue whales live on their mothers' milk for about a year, so the first thing to do would be to find an alternative. Your tribe is stone age, so they wouldn't be able to manufacture a replacement, so I would suggest capturing another adult female blue whale and make sure that the babies are compatible with the mother.

To get the whales to obey their masters, separate the babies from their surrogate mother in 6 months, but still collect milk from her, either by "bottling" it or letting the baby whales be with her during feeding times. During that time, let the whales get to know and trust their riders by having them feed the whale and having the rider play with it. Since you are talking about merfolk, I'm not entirely sure how these merfolk work and how you plan to use them as transport.

I would advise the riders to get to know the animals as any normal trainer would know their pet.